# Understanding an Array Address Function

Tags: arrays, memory-address

I am currently studying for a final in my undergraduate course and one chapter deals with the constructs behind a programming language's data types.

When discussing arrays, our professor gave us the following formula for an address function, which locates a specific index within an array:

`addr(list[k]) = addr(list[lowbound]) + ((k - lowbound) * elementSize)`

Now, I understand everything except for the last part, which is `*elementSize)`.

From what I dissect, `addr(list[lowbound])` retrieves the first index of the array (as lowbound is usually 0, referencing index 0). Then, `(k - lowbound)` moves forward k spaces by calculating the index referenced.

However, I am unsure what purpose `* elementSize` has on the function. If the second part already retrieves the necessary index, what does multiplying by `elementSize` contribute to the final product.

Comment: The first part computes the **index**, yes.  That is, the number of *elements* in the array preceding the desired one.  But each element occupies `elementSize` bytes, so to get the **byte offset** (which is what you must add to get the address), you must multiply.

Comment: Thank you, I had not considered that.